# How to translate: have you finished doing the homework (which) our teacher gave us last week?

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin

I'm mostly confused about the sentence structure. Would this be correct?
你做完上个星期老师给我们的作业了吗

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct. Good job!

Comment: gave (as in homework) is usually translated as 布置 (meaning assigned).

Comment: You answer is correct definitely. In practice, I would say 上星期老师布置的作业，你做完了吗？ I omit 我们 because we all know it's for us. I mentioned what I want to talk about first which is '上星期老师布置的作业‘  and then ask about it. This way, it gives people 'a breath' in the middle, otherwise they would have to wait you to finish the whole sentence and then digest what you just said. Sometimes, this could go terrible when you speak long sentence slowly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Chinese.

The sentences:

`你做完   上个星期  老师  给我们的作业  了吗?
你做完了 上个星期  老师  给我们的作业吗?`

are both correct.

The word "了"，just emphasize whatever you want to emphasize.

Comment: 把句子翻過來你覺得怎麼樣？對我而言更好聽一點：老師上週給我們的作業你做完了嗎？

Comment: 这几句话几乎没有区别：），日常交流中没有语感上的区别

Answer (score 1):

I think that's correct! Although I think you can put the 'le' after the action verb 'zuo wan' to read:
你做完了上个星期老师给我们的作业吗?

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is correct. Let's see the sentence:

Have you finished doing the homework (which) our teacher gave us last week?

We can divide the sentence into 2 parts:

1. Have you finished doing the homework?你完成作业了吗？

2.Our teacher gave us the homework last week.（我们）老师上周布置的作业。

Here 老师上周布置的作业 is a noun. 老师上周布置的 is an adjective.  Then we combine these 2 sentences with the repeated word 作业.

你完成老师上周布置的作业了吗？

Here is just one example and there are some other correct translation versions like 你做完了老师上星期给我们布置的作业吗，你完成了上星期老师给我们布置的作业吗，etc. Chinese people can understand your translation if there aren't many serious grammar mistakes. Usually we don't focus that much on grammatical problems when we use Chinese as Chinese people.